# Multiple RecyclerViews and adapter data offset

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have multiple RecyclerViews using common RecyclerView.Adapter. Is there is some way to tell RecyclerView to get data from adapter using some offset? Something like 1st view gets 0-15 items from adapter, 2nd view gets 15-30 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the position and and the Object List to the Fragment inside your viewpager at FragmentStatePagerAdapter :

```
 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return YourFragment.newInstance(position,yourListOfObjects);
        }
```

Then inside your YourFragment according to position take 15 items from the List and make a adpater, example with RxJava, but you can modify it, to work with regular Java:

```
int positionOfFragment;
        List<Product> list;
        Observable
                .just(list)
                .take(positionOfFragment*15)
                .subscribe(new Action1<List<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(List<Product> orders) {
                        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(orders, getActivity());
                        //setAdapter to RecyclerView;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks, I already implemented something similar with separate adapter for every page. I thought maybe there is some more elegant way to handle this situation.

Comment: @AndreiLapshin I don't think that there is any other way, that is more elegant. And there really is nothing wrong with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)?

EDITED:
Try this.
Create separate data structure for filtered data at required positions

```
private List<Object> data;
private List<Object> dataToShow;
public CustomAdapter(List<Object> data){
     this.data = data;
     this.dataToShow = new ArrayList<>(data);
}
```

...in all overriden methods use dataToShow field

create method to filter data

```
public void showDataAtPositions(int startPos, int endPos){
    dataToShow.clear();
    for(int index = 0; index < data.size(); index++){
        if(index >=startPos && index <= endPos){
            dataToShow.add(data.get(index));
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then just call this method

```
adapter.showDataAtPositions(0, 15);
adapter.showDataAtPositions(16, 30);
```

this should work

Comment: No. I have ViewPager with multiple pages where each page contains RecyclerView with fixed number of items. All RecyclerViews have the same adapter but should show items starting from some position depending on the page. So recyclerview on 1st page shows first 15 items, recyclerview on 2nd page shows next 15 items and so on

Comment: Thanks, but your second solution wouldn't work in my case. Different recyclerviews can request data from adapter at different time and even at the same time, but your adapter implementation expects that views request data one after another